# Size on disk did not increase as words were added to a table in Word

Tags: microsoft-word

Should the file on disk increase as  content is added to a Word document

We have a Word document which when first created from the template has 9 pages of empty Tables that have to filled in to be completed .

A partially completed version with half of the tables completed is showing a size on disk the same as a completed version. does this sound correct

Comment: Filling in som tables does really not require a lot of data.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking about something not specific to Word files, but how Windows store files. You are referring to the `Size on disk` when you right-click and pick `Properties`. I believe that the real size you should be considering is the one attributed with `Size` and not `Size on disk`. Read this article to differentiate them both, starting with the section "Size Matters"

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh148159.aspx

Another factor but specific to Word is that `.docx` is contained within a ZIP file, thus compression plays a role about the size, unlike what someone may think that every letter stored in Word should consume a fixed size of bytes.